# app.config cant be seen in production machine

Tags: .net, app-config

i have a windows application in vs 2012. i have added "app.config" file.
in my machine it's running fine. but in production it gives an error indicate that app config cant be seen.

is there a way to keep the file at exe path ?

Thanks,
Abdullah

Comment: Could you please include the exact error message you get?

Comment: Thanks Baduker,

Well, i have create conf file just to add following : 

 <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
  <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>   
  </startup>

After adding key above, a crystal report error has been resolved.( This is in my machine).

In Production, the same error is occur indicating app.config cant be seen.

hope it's clear.